# How to disable Antd DatePicker input with Checkbox created with dynamic List

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd, ant-design-pro

Good afternoon guys!

I have to make a form with dynamics inputs to send a list of experiences of workers.
I have trouble with endDate datepicker input, I need to disabled it in case the worker check the checkbox declaring that work experience, is his current job.

I tried to use React states to get the values of the checkbox field but after checking the values of fields, key, name and restField, I got this data:

[data form in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZIE8.jpg)

This is my code

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Form, DatePicker, Checkbox, Space } from "antd";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const onFinish = (values: any) => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      name="dynamic_form_nest_item"
      onFinish={onFinish}
      style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <Form.List name="experience">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
          <>
            {fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }) => (
              <Space
                key={key}
                style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                align="baseline"
              >
                <Form.Item
                  {...restField}
                  name={[name, "startDate"]}
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing start date" }]}
                >
                  <DatePicker picker="month" />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                  {...restField}
                  name={[name, "endDate"]}
                >
                  <DatePicker placeholder="" picker="month" />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item {...restField} name={[name, "presentJob"]}>
                  <Checkbox />
                </Form.Item>
                <span onClick={() => remove(name)}>Remove field</span>
              </Space>
            ))}
            <Form.Item>
              <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block>
                Add experience
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </>
        )}
      </Form.List>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is a link to a codesandbox example:
[codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-maria-6kdkxy?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1779)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to handle endDate. Since you are using latest version of antd, you can use `Form.useWatch` hook. You need to pass the complete path  and listen for `presentJob`. When it's true, disabled `endDate` datepicker.

Here's the complete code

```
import { Button, Form, DatePicker, Checkbox, Space } from "antd";

const EndDate = ({ name }: { name: number }) => {
  const presentJob = Form.useWatch(["experience", name, "presentJob"]);

  // It's better to hide this field if presentJob is true

  return (
    <Form.Item
      name={[name, "endDate"]}
      rules={[{ required: !presentJob, message: "Missing start date" }]}
    >
      <DatePicker placeholder="End Date" picker="month" disabled={presentJob} />
    </Form.Item>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onFinish = (values: any) => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      name="dynamic_form_nest_item"
      onFinish={onFinish}
      style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <Form.List name="experience">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
          <>
            {fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }) => (
              <Space
                key={key}
                style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                align="baseline"
              >
                <Form.Item
                  {...restField}
                  name={[name, "startDate"]}
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing start date" }]}
                >
                  <DatePicker placeholder="Start Date" picker="month" />
                </Form.Item>
                <EndDate name={name} />
                <Form.Item
                  {...restField}
                  name={[name, "presentJob"]}
                  valuePropName="checked"
                >
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      if (e.target.checked) {
                        form.setFieldValue(
                          ["experience", name, "endDate"],
                          undefined
                        );
                      }
                    }}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
                <span onClick={() => remove(name)}>Remove field</span>
              </Space>
            ))}
            <Form.Item>
              <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block>
                Add experience
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </>
        )}
      </Form.List>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: It´s clearly working as expected Muhammad! Thank you so much!